# auto font-size adjustment in fixed textarea

Tags: javascript, html

i got a problem. i have a textarea with fixed width and height (750x393px) and large font-size (eg. 100px). if you type in this textarea, the font-size should automatically be reduced so the typed text fits into the textarea. if you delete some chars the font-size should increase.

you know what i mean? there should be no overflow and no scrollbar. the font-size should decrease or increase, so that the text fits into the textarea.

a found a similar script which would be perfect, but this is a div, not a textarea and i dont know how to change this into a textarea:

HTML:

```
<div class="border" id="border">
     <div class="block" id="input" contenteditable="true">Click to edit</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#border').click(function(){
    $('#input').focus();
});

$('#input').keyup(function(event){
    while ( $(this).height() > 200) {
        $(this).css('font-size', '-=1');
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
        while ( $(this).height() <= 200 && $(this).css('font-size') <= "25px") {
            $(this).css('font-size', '+=1');
        }
            $(this).css('font-size', '-=1');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    width:400px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:'Helvetica';
}
.block:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.border {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:400px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 7px;
    cursor:text;
}
```

look at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwyqsk0s/

---

and here is a script with a textarea, but the font-size doesnt increase, if i delete some chars: http://jsfiddle.net/XCXJb/1/

can someone help me with that?

Comment: Sorry if I missed your point, but why can't you use the working div version? You can get the value from innerHTML?

Comment: @ncq i want to send the typed text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite tricky. At first, you have to find out the `height` of the text in the resizeable `textarea`. To do this, we create another `textarea`, which has `height` set to 0 px, so we can check its text `height` easily by `scrollHeight` property.

We also have to pass the text from main `textarea` to the dummy `textarea` on keypress.

**HTML**:

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="dummy"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
function getHeight(){

    $("#dummy").val( $("#textarea").val() );
    return $("#dummy").prop("scrollHeight");

}

$('#textarea').keyup(function(event){

    while ( getHeight() > $(this).height()) {
        $(this).css('font-size', '-=1');
        $("#dummy").css('font-size', '-=1');
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) {
        while ( getHeight() <= $(this).height() && $(this).css('font-size') <= "25px") {
            $(this).css('font-size', '+=1');
            $("#dummy").css('font-size', '+=1');
        }
            $(this).css('font-size', '-=1');
            $("#dummy").css('font-size', '-=1');
    }

});
```

**CSS:**

```
#textarea, #dummy {

    width: 200px; 
    font-size: 18px;

}

#textarea {

    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;

}

#dummy {

    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;

}
```

A working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/atvuf7m8/).

Answer (score 1):

This part is a problem:

```
$(this).css('font-size', '+=1');
```

It should be:

```
$(this).css('font-size', (parseInt($(this).css('font-size')) + 1) + 'px');
```