# If text is longer than its container lower the font size till the text can fit in

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a container that contains an animating text.

We define a default font size for the text, but we want to lower the font size if the text exceeds the container's width so that the text no matter how long it is can fit into the container in one line.

Here is my code so far:

```js
//The Text That would be fit into the container
let mytext = 'I was sent to earth to protect you!';

//The function to determine mytext width
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
      var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.font = font;
      var metrics = context.measureText(text);
      return metrics.width;
      };

      //width of the upperGuide container
      let width = document.getElementsByClassName("upperGuideContainer")[0].clientWidth;

      let text_Length;
      let default_size = 5.6;
   
      /* Keep lowering the default font size till the text_Length is smaller than
        its container width So that the text can fit in the container */
      do {
          text_Length = getTextWidth(mytext, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`).toFixed(2);
          //console.log("length inside: " + text_Length);
          default_size -= 0.01;
          //console.log("default_size inside: " + default_size);

      }
      while (text_Length > width);
      
  setTimeout(function(){
      //modify the font size based on text length
      upperGuideText.style.fontSize = `${default_size}vw`;

      //Append and animate the mytext
      upperGuideText.innerHTML = `${mytext}`;
      upperGuideText.classList.add("upperGuideAnimeShow");
      upperGuideText.classList.remove("upperGuideAnimeHide");
      }, 500);
```

```css
.upperGuideContainer {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 48.5vh;
    height: 26vh;
    width: 82vw;   
    outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.upperGuide {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    left: 0.5vw;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -16vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/*Animations*/

.upperGuideAnimeShow {
    animation: upperGuideShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

.upperGuideAnimeHide {
    animation: upperGuideHide 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperGuideShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 10vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: -16vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperGuideHide {
   from { opacity: 1; top: -16vh }
   to   { opacity: 0; top:  10vh }
}
```

```html
<div class = "upperGuideContainer">
 <p id="upperGuideText" class="upperGuide"></p>
</div>
```

The code works and it seems that I'm able to lower the font size when `mytext` is longer than the container, but for some reason, it doesn't lower the font size enough and we have two line sentences that don't fit in the container.

**Note**: I want the maximum possible font size that could fit in the container... So I need `default_size -= 0.01;` intact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [auto font-size adjustment in fixed textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176813/auto-font-size-adjustment-in-fixed-textarea)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I really need to debug my code...Why the code is behaving unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `white-space: nowrap;` to `upperGuide` class worked like a charm.

The problem was that when text taken more than one line the width didn't change And we should preventing line breaks to make the text width real.

```
.upperGuide {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    left: 0.5vw;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -16vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i change the default_size -= 1.0;

```js
//The Text That would be fit into the container
let mytext = 'I was sent to earth to protect you!';

//The function to determine mytext width
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
      var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.font = font;
      var metrics = context.measureText(text);
      return metrics.width;
      };

      //width of the upperGuide container
      let width = document.getElementsByClassName("upperGuideContainer")[0].clientWidth;

      let text_Length;
      let default_size = 5.6;
   
      /* Keep lowering the default font size till the text_Length is smaller than
        its container width So that the text can fit in the container */
      do {
          text_Length = getTextWidth(mytext, `bold ${default_size}vw Open Sans`).toFixed(2);
          //console.log("length inside: " + text_Length);
          default_size -= 1.0;
          //console.log("default_size inside: " + default_size);

      }
      while (text_Length > width);
      
  setTimeout(function(){
      //modify the font size based on text length
      upperGuideText.style.fontSize = `${default_size}vw`;

      //Append and animate the mytext
      upperGuideText.innerHTML = `${mytext}`;
      upperGuideText.classList.add("upperGuideAnimeShow");
      upperGuideText.classList.remove("upperGuideAnimeHide");
      }, 500);
```

```css
.upperGuideContainer {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 48.5vh;
    height: 26vh;
    width: 82vw;   
    outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.upperGuide {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    left: 0.5vw;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -16vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/*Animations*/

.upperGuideAnimeShow {
    animation: upperGuideShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

.upperGuideAnimeHide {
    animation: upperGuideHide 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperGuideShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 10vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: -16vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperGuideHide {
   from { opacity: 1; top: -16vh }
   to   { opacity: 0; top:  10vh }
}
```

```html
<div class = "upperGuideContainer">
 <p id="upperGuideText" class="upperGuide"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... plus one.. yes if we change it even to `default_size -= 0.1;` everything works again but why? what I missed

Comment: i read your comment that if the text will reduce based on the container. then i try to change that code then it works...haha

Comment: I want the maximum possible font size that could fit in the container...

Comment: try change "- =" to "+ ="

Comment: try change "default_size -= 1.0;" to "default_size += 1.0;"

Comment: I think a misunderstanding happened here... We want to lower the font size to fit in a container!

Comment: i see..wait ill try find the solution

Comment: default_size -- ;